# Copy Backend file to a different folder

Tags: vba, ms-access

[image]I am trying to copy the backend file to a different folder on form Open event. However, I get permissions error. Is there a way around it or I am doing something wrong?

```
Private Sub Form_Open()
Dim fso As Object
Dim connectionStr As String
Dim filePath As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim BackUpFolder As String

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

connectionStr = CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblAllRecords").Connect
filePath = Mid(Left(connectionStr, InStrRev(connectionStr, "\")), InStrRev(connectionStr, "=") + 1)
BackUpFolder = Mid(Left(connectionStr, InStrRev(connectionStr, "\")), InStrRev(connectionStr, "=") + 1) & "Backups"

If InStr(connectionStr, "DATABASE=") > 0 Then
    filePath = Replace(Mid(connectionStr, InStr(connectionStr, "DATABASE=") + Len("DATABASE=")), ";", "")
    fileName = Dir(filePath)
Else
    ' Handle the case where "DATABASE=" is not found
    MsgBox "The connection string is broken. Contact your database Administrator.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

' Check if the backup folder exists, and create it if necessary
If Len(Dir(BackUpFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir BackUpFolder
End If

' Ensure full paths are provided
filePath = fso.BuildPath(fso.GetParentFolderName(filePath), fileName)
BackUpFolder = fso.BuildPath(fso.GetParentFolderName(BackUpFolder), fso.GetFileName(BackUpFolder))


'fso.CopyFile filePath, BackUpFolder
FileCopy filePath, BackUpFolder

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error copying file: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation
Else
    MsgBox "File copied successfully!", vbInformation
End If

Exit Sub


End Sub
```

I can copy and past in the `Backups` folder without any issue.

Comment: If you get a permissions error then you have a permissions issue. Is this on a network? It is possible IT has blocked programmatic copying of files - happened in my office with computer upgrades. Are you able to manually copy file into folder?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a locking error? Can you add the full error message / a screen shot?

Comment: @June7 The error is on line `FileCopy filePath, BackUpFolder`. I can copy and paste in the destination folder without any problem. I was thinking that perhaps access acts like this because the file is a linked DB to the front end? making it read only?

Comment: @Andre I have never seen this type of error before. Please see update.

Comment: Just took a closer look at your code. You have an orphan `End If` line just above `End Sub`. Code would not even compile much less run. See no need for second `Exit Sub`.

Comment: I have no problem copying backend as long as no table is open and that means no form or report using table is open. Otherwise, get "permission denied".

Comment: Make sure your paths are 100% correct by adding `Debug.Print filePath, BackUpFolder` before the copy command.

Comment: If any form or any table is open, then you in most cases will receive a file locked error, and you have trouble copying the back end. In other words, if that data file is open by you or other users, then it becomes rather difficult to copy the open and "in use" file.

Comment: I assume this is a dead end then.  The front end is already distributed to multiple uses and some forms are bounded to the to backend tables. Would there be a way to back- up the database regardless of its attribute status? Say once a week?